# See a list of changes made to a wordpress site with filters and an overview?

Tags: wordpress, module

We were hacked.
And normally I would just use a backup to get back to a version of the site before the hack.
But we didn't know we got hacked. Because only a few pages and a few posts that had keywords with a specific city in them were changed.

Were we have a competitor and only one competitor in that city:D We already have a Cloudflare rule that blocks everyone from outside of Denmark access to the admin page ... So this did not work :D

I know that Wordpress has data for changes, history and so on for every pages and post.
Is there a module where I can see all these changes? And use a filter so I only see changes made by the user hacked?

I have tried: Activity Log, WP Activity Log, User Activity Log. They all make there own log, and doesn't use the WP one.

Name a module or show me where in the database har can see it and filter it my self.